# Spring REST Service Failing Without Logging

Tags: json, spring, rest

I've got a REST web service that sometimes works, and sometimes fails.  That is, my response object has several sub-objects, including one that has several Sets of related data.  The population of those sub-objects depends on the inbound parameter set.

If I submit a user id / pw that should get a failure response; i.e., a bad user id or invalid password, the response comes back out as expected.

If I submit a user id / pw that should succeed, and does not have a complicated object back out, the response comes back out as expected.

Finally, if I submit a user id / pw that should come back with an array of complicated objects attached to the response, I get a logging silent fail with a redirect to a 500 page.  For a while I was getting complaints about sub-objects on my primary complicated objects and Hibernate Session close/not available problems.  I tried initializing the entire world, which 'helped' in that I no longer got verbose exception logging from Hibernate about a session problem on a sub object, but I still get redirected to a 500 page without any logging at all.  To try to figure out if this was a problem with a nested / hidden Session problem, I tried attaching a hand created object, but still get the 500 page.

Below is my Controller code that works in some situations, but fails if the EnergyAudit[] array is populated with anything.

```
    @RequestMapping(method= RequestMethod.GET,value="login")
public @ResponseBody LoginResponse login(@RequestParam("userName") String userNameIn, @RequestParam("password") String passwordIn){

    LoginResponse theResponse = new LoginResponse();
    try{
        logger.info("Entering login for username: "+ userNameIn + " and pw: "+ passwordIn);


        //  CREATE! 
        EnergyAuditUser theUser; 

        try{ 
            // DO A BUNCH OF STUFF TO VALIDATE THEY ARE AN OK USER LEFT OUT FOR OUR PURPOSES HERE. 


        // OK.  IF WE GOT HERE, THEN WE CAN ASSUME THAT THERE IS A USER 
        // AND THEY GAVE US TEH GOOD DATA.  GOOD JOB, USER! 
        theResponse.setSuccessOrFailureSw(Constants.SUCCESS); 
        theResponse.setResponseMessage("Successfully logged in!"); 
        theResponse.setTheUser(theUser);

        // NOW, IF THE USER IS NOT A REACH USER, WE WANT TO SUBMIT BACK ANY AUDITS 
        // REACH USERS WILL HAVE ANOTHER TRANSACTION SET TO ALLOW THEM TO PICK AND CHOOSE
        // FROM THE DAYS AUDITS!
        if (theUser.getEnergyAuditUserType().equalsIgnoreCase(EnergyAuditUser.COT_AUDITOR_TYPE)){
            // WE SHOULD GET ANY AND ALL OPEN, ASSIGNED AUDITS FOR THIS USER.
            EnergyAudit[] assignedAudits = auditService.getAssignedEnergyAuditsForUser(theUser.getEnergyAuditUserId(), false,false, true, false);           
        //  theResponse.setEnergyAudits(assignedAudits);    

// NOTE THAT HERE I ATTEMPTED TO CREATE A NON-BOUND AUDIT TO EVALUATE IF THE SILENT FAILURE WAS HIBERNATE SESSION RELATED.  NO LOVE!
            EnergyAudit bogusAudit = new EnergyAudit(); 
            bogusAudit.setStartingInsulationRvalue(32); 
            bogusAudit.setStreetAddress("123 Chiefy Street"); 
            bogusAudit.setAuditDate(new java.util.Date()); 

            EnergyAudit[] bogusResults = new EnergyAudit[1]; 
            bogusResults[0] = bogusAudit; 

            theResponse.setEnergyAudits(bogusResults);

        }



        // THIS USER / LOSER OUGHT TO BE GOOD TO GO!
        return theResponse;
```

What is driving me crazy is that my console gives me no information about what is going on here.  Any insight is greatly appreciated.

brian